# How to get from working tree clean to working directory clean

Tags: git, git-status

After giving the Git command `git status` I am getting `working tree clean` instead of `working directory clean`. How do I get to working directory clean?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of git console; both the git status command and the result.

Comment: They mean the same thing.  "Working directory" was just the wrong string.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to downgrade your version of `git`. Not authoritative, but [this post](https://github.com/mnagel/clustergit/issues/18) mentions:

> Git v2.9.1 changed the response from a clean git status to working
>   tree clean instead of working directory clean; this change breaks
>   clustergit for 2.9.1 users.

Authoritatively, the [release notes for 2.9.1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.9.1.txt):

> - "git status" used to say "working directory" when it meant "working
>     tree".